# I'm having trouble making a tool that can break certain things in Minecraft Bedrock

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

When I choose a tool, and I activate the command, it tells me the error is where I put the tools name. For instance,

```
/give @p minecraft:diamond_shovel 1 0 {CanDestroy:["minecraft:dirt"],Unbreakable:1}
```

In this case, it would say there is an error at >"minecraft:diamond_shovel"<
I am on switch if that helps at all.

Answer (score 1):

The example given in the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/give#Arguments) should potentially help you identify the issues you are having with your command

```
/give @p iron_shovel 1 0 {"minecraft:can_destroy":{"blocks":["grass"]}}
```

And the syntax for [adding an enchantment](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/give#Examples), I believe also needs to be specified as well:

```
/give @r diamond_sword{Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:sharpness",lvl:10}]} 1
```

As you can see my comparison, there are potentially a few mismatches in the syntax. So your command should look like this:

```
/give @p diamond_shovel{Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:unbreakable",lvl:1}]} 1 0 {"minecraft:can_destroy":{"blocks":["grass"]}}
```